# How to find the saved Wifi Password in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, password

I connected my laptop with my home Wifi connection but now I forget the password and I want to login on my mobile device as well. Can you tell me how can I check my saved password so that I can use it on my mobile? Or do I need to change the Wifi Password by accessing the router's settings?

Answer (score 21):

Open up a terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>  ) then issue:

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
ls -la
```

Now just cat out whichever file matches the connection you need to view:

```
sudo cat 'my_cool_network' # you MUST use sudo as file is root owned. quote if file name contains spaces
```

In output look for something like this:

```
[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=ele55Hroad
```

As you can see my WiFi password is  `ele55Hroad`

Above works on Ubuntu 18.10+

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 16.04. Just tried it and posted a shorter answer based on yours.

Answer (score 3):

## One-liner

A one-liner you can use:

```
sudo grep --with-filename psk= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

For example:

```bsh
$ sudo grep --with-filename psk= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SHAW-999999:psk=99999A999999
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SHAW-999999-5G:psk=99999A999999
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SHAW-999999-5G:psk=999999999999
```

After "`system-connections/`" you will see your WiFi network name. EG "`SHAW-999999`". Then you will see your password after "`:psk=`". EG "`99999A999999`". WiFi network name and password were redacted in case my neighbour is hoping for a free bus ride :)